# Engine Block / Frame is at 12 volts

Tags: electrical, short

I tried the tradition "pull fuses one at a time" method and still can't find the short.

People from other forums have said that the engine block being hot may be symptomatic of a bad ground cable -- but this doesn't make sense to me.

So basically, symptoms are:

1) Parasitic Draw at > 0.2 amp. (Not sure of the exact number -- waiting for another multimeter as mine won't give a reading at the 10A setting)

2) Engine block at 12 Volts -- so about .5/.6 voltage drop between positive terminal and frame/block.

3) Car will not start / no indicator lights, etc. (Usb accessories seem to work, however.)

4) None of the fuses will stop the parasitic draw

What do I do next? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Are you measuring the engine block against the ground strap/car body? If so, then that's really surprising; there's no way the engine is insulated from the body.

Comment: Thanks, glad to be here! No, I'm measuring it against the negative terminal on the battery (12V) and the positive terminal (-.5 volts). That still feels very unexpected to me?

Comment: DVOMs measure the difference between the com lead and the volt lead. So if you have ~12v on the volt lead and ~0v on the com lead than the difference would be ~12v. Try running a wire from the engine to the b- terminal and see if it corrects the reading. A 500mV voltage drop on a wire suggests either a load on the circuit or resistance in the circuit. Even with the engine running you should expect to see a very small < 100mV drop on the b+ or - cables. If the engine truly is the source of the draw try disconnecting the alternator as a shorted regulator can cause draw.

Comment: Also, edit your post so that it contains an actual question. Even if its something simple like, what do i do next?

Comment: Try disconnecting every wire on the starter and measure again.

Comment: Do you have the battery ground strap attached? If not, then this all seems right to me; the battery ground terminal will float, and drain from the positive terminal will bring it to the same voltage as the rest of the car. If so, then there's a problem with the ground strap.

Comment: please edit the question and say precisely where you are placing each probe. Voltage is always a relative measurement, it makes no sense to simply say the block is "at 12v"

Comment: Yeah you guys are right ... the way I was doing it, with a lead at an unhooked negative and pos lead at the engine block, 12V is expected. Im an idiot, and thanks

Comment: Quick request - can you please remove the solution from your question and post it as an answer? That makes it much better for future visitors, (and you can also get more reputation points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With the negative terminal detached and the positive terminal attached, measuring a ~12V drop from the unattached negative terminal to the engine block with negative lead at the terminal and positive lead at the block is expected behavior as the multi-meter completes the circuit and acts as a large resistor across which there is a voltage drop.
2. Parasitic draw of ~ .2 A was is also expected behavior.
3. In my case, I experienced a sudden loss of electronic power steering while driving; after parking, the car refused to start. It turned out to be a bad / burned connection from one of the bolted on wires leading from the positive terminal. Unbolting and cleaning the connection fixed the problem.